# deleting and ordering columns in a big dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have this dataframe (with the same values for each column to facilitate the example)

```
df = data.frame(x1 = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                x2 = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                x3 = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                x4 = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                x5 = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                x6 = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                x7 = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                x8 = c(1,2,3,4,5))
```

I want to put x7 and x8 at the place of x2 and x3 while keeping the names of x7 and x8 and deleting x2 and x3 at the same time (the dataframe I am working on is really big and I can't use the simple method of `df[,c(1,7,8,4,5,6)]`) so I am looking for a function to make it easier to apply. thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate on why `df[,c(1,7,8,4,5,6)]` is not a satisfying solution?

Comment: because the real dataframe I am working on includes 100 variables and I need to delete about 10 variables and substitue them with other 10 variables that I created.

Comment: By "I can't use the simple method", do you  mean that you have so many columns that writing all of them out would be tedious?

Comment: yes exactly the problem I am facing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this flexible base R approach:

```
reorder_fun <- function(move_cols, splitpoint, datframe){
  a <- 1:grep(splitpoint, names(datframe))
  b <- c(a, grep(paste(move_cols, collapse = "|"), names(datframe)))
  newdf <- cbind(datframe[, b],
                 datframe[, setdiff(names(datframe), names(datframe[b]))])
  newdf
}

reorder_fun(move_cols = c("x7", "x8"), splitpoint = "x1", datframe = df)
```

Output:

```
#   x1 x7 x8 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6
# 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
# 2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
# 3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3
# 4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4
# 5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5
```

This allows you to move the desired columns to other positions (i.e, after the 3rd column is:

```
reorder_fun(move_cols = c("x7", "x8"), splitpoint = "x3", datframe = df)
```

or if you wanted to move different columns

```
reorder_fun(move_cols = c("x5", "x8"), splitpoint = "x1", datframe = df)
```

Answer (score 3):

Would this work ?

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  relocate(c(x7,x8), .after = c(x2, x3)) %>% 
  select(-c(x2, x3))
#>   x1 x7 x8 x4 x5 x6
#> 1  1  1  1  1  1  1
#> 2  2  2  2  2  2  2
#> 3  3  3  3  3  3  3
#> 4  4  4  4  4  4  4
#> 5  5  5  5  5  5  5
```